# Meteor Collections behaving differently when uploaded to a live environment

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm having a issue where my mongo collection is behaving differently after I've uploaded it to Meteor's servers. Locally everything works perfectly and I'm not seeing any issues when running meteor logs either.

What I'm trying to do is this:

In my collection called RaceList I have several entry's. Each has a unique id, an array of users and a 'live' variable which is a boolean.
Every hour I update this collection by removing the live race, setting the next race's live variable to true and adding another race to the end of the collection.

All this is working for me locally but after uploading to my Meteor server something strange is happening. If I don't and anybody to the array of users in the next race to turn live it seems to be working ok but as soon as I join the race, for some reason, the race immediately after the one I have just joined will become the live race and the race I joined is skipped...

Here is the code from my server that is executed every hour:

```
updateRaces: ->

    # Remove the finished race
    Meteor.call 'removeLiveRace'

    # Set the next race to live
    Meteor.call 'updateLiveRace'

    # Add another race to the collection
    Meteor.call 'insertNewRace'
```

And here is the code from my Meteor.methods

```
removeLiveRace: ->

    id = RaceList.findOne( { live: true } )?._id

    if id

        RaceList.remove _id: id


updateLiveRace: ->

    id = _.first( RaceList.find().fetch() )._id

    RaceList.update id, $set: live: true


insertNewRace: ->

    RaceList.insert
        live  : false
        users : []
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm still just getting started with Meteor so any advice to make this code more efficient/safe would be great!

Thanks : )

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't look like you're using Cron, the standard warning message still applies to you:

> **Caveats**
>
> Beware, SyncedCron probably won't work as expected on certain shared
>   hosting providers that shutdown app instances when they aren't
>   receiving requests (like Heroku's free dyno tier or Meteor free
>   galaxy).

In other words, because you are using free services, any moments of app shutdown will mess with any Cron/time-based functions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was because my collection was sending an entry to the bottom of the collection when I added more than 1 user to it. I have no idea why this would happen? I just set the collection to sort by createdAt wherever I query it and that fixed the problem.